# Extracting the project number with python regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Good day everyone. I want to extract the last digit numbers after the slash symbol from the `project_name` column. Currently, I'm working on it but have some issues as follow:

1. **How could I extract the last digit numbers after the slash symbol without getting the result with a square bracket in it?** Because right now I have the code that almost works but the result always has a square bracket in it

My code:

```
def project_name(name):
    return re.findall(r'\d{3}$',name)

data['project_name'] = data['project_name'].apply(project_name)
```

The data:

```
project_name    
 ----------
   ASAHI,PT-PRO/PTN/06-2012/192          
   CIMB NIAGA-PRO/PTN/06-2012/174        
   FRAMAS INDONESIA-PRO/PTN/06-2012/210    
   DM STOCK 2015   
   PERBAIKAN OH TM 366 PLANT DAWUAN 
   Ruko-PRO/PTN/03-2012/47
```

My output:

```
 (Expected)project_name   
 ----------     
   192            
   174            
   210            
   NaN
   NaN            
   NaN            
    47
```

All advice and input are appreciated. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and add `/` to regex:

```
data['project_name'] = data['project_name'].str.extract(r'/(\d{3}$)')
print (data)
  project_name
0          192
1          174
2          210
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
```

Solution with `findall`:

```
data['project_name'] = data['project_name'].str.findall(r'/(\d{3}$)').str[0]
```

And your solution should be change with `next` and `iter` for return default value `np.nan` if no match:

```
def project_name(name):
    return next(iter(re.findall(r'/(\d{3})$',name)), np.nan)

data['project_name'] = data['project_name'].apply(project_name)
print (data)
  project_name
0          192
1          174
2          210
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
```

Comment: Hi yes now it worked but I just realized that in the lower rows I have a strange output due to a format difference in the original dataset. I'll update my question and show how it looks

Comment: I have updated my dataset, current output, and expected output that I wanted to get. Because I just want to get the 3 digit numbers after the slash symbol. Sometimes there are different project name format that have 3 numbers in the middle and I don't want to include it

Comment: Ok I got it this way and now it worked as what I expected. Thanks a lot for the superb explanation

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
def project_name(name):
    return re.findall(r'\d{3}$',name)
```

use

```
def project_name(name):
    return re.findall(r'\d{3}$',name)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the value in list is only one, we can return the value of `0th` index

```
def project_name(name):
    return re.findall(r'\d{3}$',name)[0]

data['project_name'] = data['project_name'].apply(project_name)
```

Comment: explanation needs to be provided along with answer